# Why do my distinct functions not work in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In my student table I have some student's imformation.

```
id |phone        |name    |age    |sex 
---|-------------|------- |-------|-------
1  |13553841211  |name1   |11     |1 
2  |13553841212  |name2   |12     |0 
3  |13553841213  |name3   |13     |1 
4  |13553841214  |name4   |14     |0 
5  |13553841214  |name5   |15     |1
```

Now I want to select all the information. If the count of the phone is greater than 1, I want to return only one row whose id is max. 
I want the result :

```
id |phone        |name    |age    |sex 
---|-------------|------- |-------|-------
1  |13553841211  |name1   |11     |1 
2  |13553841212  |name2   |12     |0 
3  |13553841213  |name3   |13     |1 
5  |13553841214  |name5   |15     |1
```

My code is here, what's wrong?

```
select name,phone,id from student where 
id in (select max(id) from student having count(phone)>=1);


select name,distinct(phone),id from student;
```

Comment: The reason why your code doesn't work is because `distinct` applies to all columns in the select list. It doesn't make sense to have some columns excluded from the distinctness in the way you have tried. Instead, you need to identify the row with the highest id per phone number and then select that row. There are a number of ways of doing that, as shown in the solutions you have been given. Which one is most performant for your database and data is up to you to test.

Comment: Because `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
select *
from
(
select name, id, phone, age, sex, row_number() over(partition by phone order by id desc) as stu_ord
from student
)
where stu_ord = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**TRY This:**

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM STUDENT t1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT MAX(ID) as ID,phone
   FROM student 
   GROUP BY phone
)t2 
ON t1.ID =t2.ID
```

Comment: Thanks.It works.It should use on  t1.ID =t2.ID,not WHERE t1.ID =t2.ID

Comment: t2 needs an alias on that `max(id)` or the join won't work

Comment: @Sarly Its typo ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT name,phone,id
FROM student s1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 'next'
    FROM student s3 
    WHERE s3.phone = s1.phone
    AND s3.id > s1.id)
```